# How to specify -O flag or otherwise set __debug__ for python interpreter in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: python, visual-studio, flags

I would like to run my python code (and unit tests) with **debug** set to False (so that assertions are ignored). This seems to require either using the -O flag on the Python interpreter, or setting the PYTHONOPTIMIZE environment variable. Is this possible in Visual Studio 2017, and if so how?

Visual Studio usually has some option or property settings that allow one to specify compiler flags and the like, but I cannot find them for Python (I am using Anaconda 5.2.0 in VS 15.8.5).